# HP Proliant server DL180 g6 smart array p410 fatal error

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, hp-proliant

I HAVE ONE HP PROLIANT SERVER DL 180 G6. THIS SERVER RESTART SUDDENLY, SOME TIME TWO OR THREE TIME IN  A DAY SOME TIME AFTER 2 DAYS OR AFTER 7 DAYS. ([Reboot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdumI.jpg))

I have run the hp smart storage administrator tool ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSlHk.png)).

```
ADU REPORT


ADU Version                             2.30.6.0
Diagnostic Module Version               8.3.6.0
Time Generated                          Friday January 20, 2017 2:22:11PM

Device Summary:
   Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot

Consolidated Error Report:
   Controller: Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot
      Message: An unknown cache error was detected.
   Controller: Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot
      Message: The cache is permanently disabled.

Report for Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot
--------------------------------------------

Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot : Device Error Report

Device                            Severity Error                                
--------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------ 
Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot Warning  An unknown cache error was detected.
Smart Array P410 in Embedded Slot Critical The cache is permanently disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not better why tahn to call HP support to request a tech
Last time I remember the Tech guy replaced the Smart Array/raid controller
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your RAID cache module is defective, so the controller completely disabled the write-back cache. It does not apper to be a simple battery problem; maybe the DRAM cache memory itself is broken.

There is nothing you can do yourself, short of buying another identical controller and replace the failed one. However, if you can, open a support call with HP and ask for a replacement.